# Is the Klingon's view of the Federation supposed to reflect the (future) Federation's view of the Borg?

Tags: star-trek, borg, klingon, star-trek-discovery

In the first two episodes of *Star Trek Discovery*, T'Kuvma speaks of the Federation as the enemy.  His main argument against the Federation was

> they would rob the Klingons of the individuality.

This struck me as *very* similar to the Federation's hatred of the Borg; the reason the Federation resists the Borg is their violation of individuality, for example (emphasis mine):

> LAFORGE: All right, think of it this way. Every time you talk about yourself, you use the word we. We want this, we want that. You don't even know how to think of yourself as a single individual. You don't say, I want this, or I am Hugh. We are all separate individuals. I am Geordi. I choose what I want to do with my life. I make decisions for myself. For somebody like me, **losing that sense of individuality is almost worse than dying.** <sub>'I, Borg' *TNG*</sub>

So, I am curious about whether any comments have been made by writers etc. whether, out of universe, the audience is expected to view the Klingon's hatred of the Federation as comparable to the Federation's hatred of the Borg?

Comment: I've removed the word "Spoiler" in your title according to a meta consensus [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/is-it-important-to-mark-spoiler-questions-as-such)

Comment: I don't know about writers, etc. but T'Kuvma's sentiment is echoed in the future by other Klingons. I can't recall exactly where, but I seem to remember it coming up in ST VI: Undiscovered Country, and perhaps also in TNG and DS9 but don't quote me on it...

Comment: They're just showing us what it was like [before the Klingons joined the Federation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91340/).

Comment: Long time no see!  (For the record, that's some other Praxis above.)   There may be a definitive answer to this at some point, but there needs to be more commentary from the creative staff first.

Comment: not likely imo - the Federation's problem with the Borg wasn't their lack of individuality per se, it was that the Borg relentlessly, by violent force, dictated their will upon unwilling civilizations. Federation membership, on the other hand, is entirely voluntary and predicated on meeting many requirements. Even if the Klingon's didn't *like* the Federation's values, the Federation wasn't in any way attempting to impose themselves forcefully upon the Klingons. The Klingons so far are being shown to be xenophobic and racist which is not how the Federation viewed the Borg.

Comment: Geordi's quote above isn't saying that the loss of individuality itself is an evil - he's saying that being forced into the loss is the evil. I don't think the Federation would have a problem if the Borg were a peaceful race and you could willingly subsume into them.

Comment: @Praxis definitely; I don't mind if this question goes quiet for a while and is revisited when more information comes out as the show progresses.  Good to see you again also!

Comment: @NKCampbell the preachings of T'Kuvma indicates a complete lack of trust in the Federation's sincerity and suspicion of the Federation encroaching on their border.  The way I interpreted that was T'Kuvma viewing the Federation as an invading force not dissimilar to the Borg.

Answer (score 3):

The Klingons in *Discovery* are more worried with losing their national identity than their individual identities. Furthermore while the Borg are viewed as nigh-unstoppable, the Federation is for the most part viewed as weak.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. I recommend a look at our [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) to writing quality answers.

Answer (score 0):

The sentiment of people viewing the Federation as Borg-like was expressed before in Star Trek series (especially DS9). Garak and Quark had an entire conversation about it.

Comment: Could you cite said conversation?

Comment: It was Michael Eddington who told Sisko in *DS9* that the Federation were as bad as, or maybe worse than, the Borg.

Comment: The conversation between Garak and Quark did not specifically mention the Borg, but I'm linking to it just so that folks can judge for themselves by what was actually said. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VhSm6G7cVk

Comment: The Garak/Quark conversation is very funny and compares the Federation to root beer, of all things! Hilarious.