# Who is the tallest member species in the United Federation of Planets?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

I've been looking for the tallest average height but so far the search is proving difficult. It appears that most every member species seem to be roughly the same height. From Human to Vulcan to Benzite, the males seem to average about 6 foot tall. Is there any member species that average much taller? The Klingons seem to average in the 6'4"+ range with some much taller but they aren't UFP members.

Edit:
I understand that their height, without CG, will generally be limited by the actual height of the actors in the role. That would limit height to approx. 7 foot or less.

Comment: The [Kelpien](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kelpien) ([Commander Saru](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Saru)'s race) are tall by comparison to other races but they are not part of the Federation yet. Saru is [reputably 2.032 m (6' 8") tall](https://ca.startrek.com/article/inside-discovery-doug-jones) while [Doug Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doug_Jones_(actor)) (the actor who plays Saru) is 1.92 m (6' 3½") tall and the actors chosen to play other Kelpien roles have been tall either by stature or trickery.

Comment: There's Mr Homn but it's never said what species he is

Comment: [Maihar'du](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Maihar%27du) is also worth a mention, but again, we're not clear if the [Hupyrian](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Hupyrian) people are part of the Federation.

Comment: It appears that Zaldans may be in the running too. An example of that race named 'Rondon', TNG, 'Coming of Age', is presented as 7 feet. https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Rondon

Answer (score 1):

There are several serious contenders mentioned in the EU novels.

Fleet Admiral Akaar (a **Capellan**) is 2.5 metres tall. Apparently his height was not atypical of his race.

> And the third person towered over everybody. Fleet Admiral Leonard
> Akaar, who had been the Starfleet liaison to the president since
> Admiral Ross’s retirement last year, was **from Capella IV, where they
> bred them big. The admiral—who had passed his centennial birthday—was
> two and a half meters tall,** with long white hair and the face of a man
> who had pretty much seen everything.
>
> <sub><sup>[ST: A Singular Destiny](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/A_Singular_Destiny)</sup></sub>

One of the **Briamosite** delegates is approximately 2.5 metres tall.

> "This is Sarvus, Leader of all the Briamosite systems, final arbiter
> of multiple-world decisions." **Pliver introduced them to the elegantly
> appointed, two-and-one-half-meter-tall Briamosite** who had stifled his
> laughter at Uhura-kirk's comment. "And Vice-Leader Chellea," Pliver
> continued, indicating the tallest member of the naturally towering
> alien delegation.

*[TAS: The Slaver Weapon - Official Novelisation](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Slaver_Weapon)*)

Although the novel doesn't end with an *explicit* agreement on a treaty between Briamos and the Federation to join, that was the purpose of the visit, which ultimately ended with a big thumbs up from the Briamosite delegation. Additionally their planet and its surroundings are seen in the [Star Trek: Star Charts](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Star_Charts) factbook in solid blue, strongly indicating Federation membership.

---

As to the tallest member seen *on screen*, that's probably a tie-in between the **Arkenites** at 2.2 metres

[image]

and the **Klingons** (yes, [I know](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91340/did-the-klingons-join-the-federation/121059#121059)) at 2.3 meters.

[image]

Comment: But are they members of the Federation? The Briamosite are not listed in [Federation races and cultures](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Federation_races_and_cultures) but apparently they made a decision to ally with the Federation during a mission from [The Slaver Weapon](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Slaver_Weapon).

Comment: We need to remember Mr. Homn too. I can't seem to find anything on what race he is, although i could assume he is Betazoid as well. He was pretty tall, towering over Captain Picard and many other Starfleet officers.

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - His species isn't named (afaik) so I've excluded him along with Zek's manservant.

Comment: Good point, @Valorum

Comment: @MissouriSpartan - For all we know, he's freakishly tall for his race, like comparing the average human with Robert Wadlow.

Comment: @Valorum That last picture of the Klingon coming down the shuttle ramp is Security officer Koral, played by basketball star James Worthy. His 6'9" height is still visually striking even if he weren't standing on the ramp a foot above ground level.